# Batch File to check folder contents and restart print spooler not working

Tags: windows, batch-file

We have an issue where a 24in plotter keeps freezing up and the only way to fix it is to stop the print spooler, delete the printer contents, then restart the spooler. For non-technical people this is quite difficult so I thought I'd write a simple batch file (below) to assist...

```
@echo off
echo Press any key to fix Plotter frozen print queue.
pause
sc stop Spooler
echo Spooler service stopped, please wait.
timeout 5
if exist "C:\Windows\System32\spool\PRINTERS\*.*" (
echo Files are in the print queue
echo **check no other printer is being used before continuing**
pause
del "C:\Windows\System32\spool\PRINTERS\*.*"
) else (
echo There are no files in any print queues
)
sc start Spooler
echo Spooler service restarting, please wait.
timeout 5
pause
```

Now this works all apart from the feedback from the folder... if the folder is empty it still says that there is something there!?

I know it's a question within a question but I can't also see a way of checking the spooler status when it is running... so I've used timeout to delay things

The service has states but I don't know how to check these in a batch file, I also don't know the states of running and stopped :/

```
STATE              : 2  START_PENDING
STATE              : 3  STOP_PENDING
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think it's something to do with the argument as if I put a filetype it seems to work... it doesn't want to work for unknown file types...

Comment: [As a resource, this may be useful to you.](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/sourcecode.php?src=printing_xp), with regards to print status. [There's a few other files relating to handling printers / printing via batch here](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/batexamples.php?fc=P)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To know, if there are files in the folder:

```
dir /b "C:\Windows\System32\spool\PRINTERS\*" | findstr "^" 2>nul && (
  echo files found 
) || (
  echo no files found
)
```

To get the spooler state:

```
for /f "tokens=3,4" %%a in ('sc query spooler ^|find "STATE"') do set "state=%%a %%b"
echo Spooler state: %state%
```

(probably you need `%%a` only for numerical comparison or `%%b` only for string comparison)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply.
Spooler state I was missing the query command so thank you for that.
As for the main problem I tried the code above and the batch file won't even run now :/

Comment: I missed a `(` (edited). What does `won't even run` mean? Run it from an open `cmd` window, not per DoubleClick to see any messages, ideally with `echo on`.

Comment: won't even run as in the batch file would not launch a cmd type window, with the ( in place it works fine, thank you.

Comment: It *did* launch a window, but it exited with a syntax error because of the missing `(`. You should have seen the window flashing up for less than a tenth of a second (easy to not notice though). That's why (at least during development/troubleshooting) you should start a batch file from an already open command prompt instead of double-clicking it.